# Installing a clean version of OS X

Tags: macos, mac, install

I am currently downloading yosemite from the app store. I have Lion installed. I want a clean install. But i don't have a bootable cd/usb and I don't need to save any data.

Can i do the following or is there a better way?

Create a partition. Install yosemite on it. Delete the other partition where now lion runs

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Creating a new partition, installing Yosemite (or whatever Mac OS you care) there and then copying/downloading the installer onto it is a great way to then erase your Primary partition.

Then you can cleanly install OS X on to the first partition and then delete the "staging" partition, finally resizing the first partition to take the whole drive again.

My way is "better" since if you install on to the second partition, deleting the first might leave you with space you can't re-grow the second partition to recover the first. I've never seen a case where I can't delete follow on partitions and then grow the first to take up all space.

Comment: When the Yosemite installer is run from the Applications/ folder, it is deleted automatically.  So, if you are concerned about downloading the installer multiple times in order to re-install the OS, be sure to save a copy of it somewhere before running it initially.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to do a clean install. Install OS X Yosemite. Then boot to the recovery partition, go to Disk Utility. Erase the partition, and reinstall a clean copy of OS X on the erased partition.

Answer (score -1):

Create a usb drive installer and wipe the disk when booted from the installer. There is an app that will help make an installer disk - http://diskmakerx.com/

I do this for any update to OS X where I want a clean install.

Comment: do you read that i wrote i dont have an usbdrive

Comment: @user3613886 take a closer look at DiskMakerX. It works with *any* partition that can be made Bootable. It is not limited to USB. I have used it on secondary partitions on MacBooks. I have also used it on an external drive that has partitions for the last six versions of Mac OS X.,